# Aura components do not support custom classes with constructors?

Tags: apex, aura, serialization

We have a situation where we have an `@AuraEnabled` endpoint, that we want to take a custom class as an argument.  This works fine for LWC, but older Aura components seem to have a serialization issue if we include any constructors.

Consider the following:

```
public class DataReq {
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String myName { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String myValue { get; set; }
    
    public DataReq(){} 
}
```

```
public with sharing class TestController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String doThing(DataReq request){
        System.debug('in doThing ' + request);
        return 'success - doThing: ' + request;
    }
}
```

When we use an Aura component to call `TestController.doThing()`, it will fail with `System.TypeException: DataReq does not have a no-arg constructor` prior to reaching our debug statement.  Merely removing or commenting out the constructor for DataReq, and it will work just fine.

Of course, we want to have constructor(s) in our use case (that have some initialization logic in them)... is this a limitation of Aura that I'm unaware of?  We're on API version `49.0`.